# Custom post WpQuery foreach loop only returning one result after heredoc added

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, heredoc

I've been scratching my head over this one for a day or two. I'm trying to get WordPress to print all the recent posts using a shortcode that calls a function in `functions.php`. I managed to get the code working but it printed to the top of the page because I suppose PHP `echo`s by default and I needed to `return`. The other problem is that at the moment it only prints the single most recent result. The loop was working before I started using `HEREDOC` but I figured I need to use that to return instead of echo.

Code:

```
add_shortcode('recentvideos' , 'printrecenttv');

function printrecenttv(){
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => 4, // Number of recent posts thumbnails to display
        'post_status' => 'publish', // Show only the published posts
        'post_type'  => "tv" //Show only Videos
    ));
    foreach($recent_posts as $post) : 
        $perm = get_permalink($post['ID']);
        $imgurl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post['ID'], 'full');
return <<<HTML
     <div class="videoposter">
        <a class="posterlink" href="$perm">
                <img class="posterimg" src="$imgurl">
            </a>
    </div>
HTML;
     endforeach; wp_reset_query();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is the return.

return returns the value and stop further code execution, meaning that all code after return will not run.

You start your foreach, run the code and use the return, you passed heredoc to the return (the first iteration of the loop) and thats it, return stops all further code execution.

You need to create a variable outside the loop, lets say `$html = '';` and each iteration concatenate the html that you need. After the foreach is done you can check if `$html` is not empty and then return the `$html`

```
$html = '';

foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
    $perm   = get_permalink($post['ID']);
    $imgurl = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post['ID'], 'full');

    $html .= '<div class="videoposter">';
    $html .=   '<a class="posterlink" href="' . $perm . '">';
    $html .=     '<img class="posterimg" src="' . $imgurl . '">';
    $html .=   '</a>';
    $html .= '</div>';
}

if (!empty($html)) {
  return $html;
}
```

You can of course use heredoc if you want.

Hope this helps =]

Comment: Ah - That makes much more sense! Thanks so much!

Comment: I should add - I did have to change `html .=` to `$html .=` though